# Can I update kernel of 12.04 to 3.5 of 12.04.2?

Tags: 12.04

Kernel in 12.04.2 is 3.5. My kernel in 12.04 amd64 is 3.2.0-40.
Can I update kernel of 12.04 to 3.5 of 12.04.2 ?

LTS Hardware Enablement Stack says: The hardware enablement stack is only intended for use on x86 hardware at this time.
Does this include amd64?
Thanks

Comment: That post said mainline kernel do not include any Ubuntu patches or drivers . Is there a deb file of kernel of 12.04.2 that I can install in 12.04 ? Then if there are any compatible issues ?

Comment: anything that you install other than official ubuntu channel might have compatibility issues...